# Jquery validate checkbox by class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i want to validate check box by jquery validation adding rule and message. i did this way but some where i made the mistake for which code is not working.

i want user has to select one checkbox at least before form submit.

### code

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" class="clschk" />x
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]"  class="clschk"/>y
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]"  class="clschk"/>z
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
```

### js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            '.clschk': {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages: {
            '.clschk': {
                required: "You must check at least 1 box",
                maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add validation messages based on class by using **addClassRules** method and then you can override the default messages by below code

**$.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,"You must check at least 1 box");**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addClassRules({

    clschk:{
        cRequired: true,
        cmaxlength: 2
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }


});

$('#myform').validate();

$.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,"You must check at least 1 box");

$.validator.addMethod("cmaxlength", $.validator.methods.maxlength,"You must check at least 1 box");

});
```

updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Nbcj9/398/

Comment: what this line will do $('#myform').validate();?

Comment: $('#myform').validate() initializes the validator and the validator will start validating the form.

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316776/can-we-use-wildcard-with-jquery-validator

Answer (score 2):

The issue is simply because the keys of the `rules` object must be equal to the `name` property of the element, not a selector for it. Try this:

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        'test[]': { // note here
            required: true,
            maxlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'test[]': { // and here
            required: "You must check at least 1 box",
            maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('valid form submitted');
        return false; // for demo
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rv16fqp4/)

Comment: Not by default using jQuery validate. You would need to re-write how their rules engine works, or find another validation library.

Comment: some time i have checkboxes whose name start with student_ after under score name is dynamic like hobbies_0_name,hobbies_1_name so on..in this case how to handle using wild card....idea plzz.

Comment: can we work with wild card for name when name is not fixed?

Comment: No, it has to be the exact name of the element.

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nbcj9/ they use class name...how can i use it for my code where i will set validation msg too.

Comment: That's using a plugin which is changing how the rules application works, as I mentioned above. If that works for your scenario, go for it.

Comment: can u give me fiddle using that plugin where i will set validation message. i tried but my own validation message is not showing.

Comment: u did not also mention can we use wild card if name is not static or fixed?

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316776/can-we-use-wildcard-with-jquery-validator