# Can we use wildcard with jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

when element name is not fixed then can we use wild card there for specifying name.

### below code will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        $("[name^=test]"): {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 1
        }
    },
    messages: {
        $("[name^=test]"): {
        required: "You must check at least 1 box",
        maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
    });


});
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
<form id="myform" runat="server"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="test_1_p1" class="clschk" />x 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="test_2_p2" class="clschk"/>y 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="test_3_p3" class="clschk"/>z 
<input id="age" type="text" name="age" /> <input type="submit" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You are looking for id starts with 'test', you need to use name attribute [name^=test]

Comment: post some sample code as per my situation for better clarity. thanks

Comment: @DinoMyte update as u said.

Comment: @DinoMyte now tell me does the above code works ?

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885056/jquery-validate-set-rule-using-wildcard-to-find-target-fields

Comment: @koolhuman u gave a nice example but i am working checkbox and i can not add rules for each checkbox because i want user has to select any not all. so tell me how to customize the code.

Comment: in order for jquery validate to work on the checkboxes as a group you should have some common name or class. In your case you have a common class and thus you should use the addclass method. I don't know why you want to add rules using wildcard on names, because names are different.

Comment: @koolhuman if possible....would you post a sample code because i posted my code here.

Comment: @mou .. what you are asking is not possible. For validation to work on checkboxes you have to have same name (then you can specify rules using addmethod) or same class (then you can specify rules using addclass method). But what you are asking is having different name but still work as a group ? this is something not possible.

Comment: can't we do that by class name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107778/discussion-between-koolhuman-and-mou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the best way to  achieve this goal is to consider:

1. the parameters of validate (rules and messages) are json objects.
2. a json object can be created at runtime if it must have dymanic content
3. you need a custom rule to detect the max number of selected check boxes
4. you need to define a function to define the corresponding error message (the max value cannot be written in more than one place to avoid confusion and so side effects).

So, a possible solution for your problem can be:

```js
// global variable to save the validator object
var validator;


// a new rule to test if the selected checkboxes are more than the max or less than one
$.validator.addMethod('checkboxMax', function (value, elem, param) {
  var cacheCheckedElements = $('[name^=test]:checked');
  if (cacheCheckedElements.length < 1 || cacheCheckedElements.length > param.max) {
    return false;
  } else {
    validator.resetForm();
    return true;
  }
});


$(function () {
  // on ready: create the two json object: rules and messages
  var myRules = {};
  var myMessages = {};
  $('[name^=test]').each(function (index, element) {
    myRules[element.name] = {
      checkboxMax: {
        max: 2
      }
    };
    myMessages[element.name] = {
      checkboxMax: function(params, element) {
        return 'Check no more than ' + params.max + ' boxes ';
      }
    };
  });
  
  // use the previous fields (myRules and myMessages) as arguments
  validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: myRules,
    messages: myMessages,
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" runat="server">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="test_1_p1" class="clschk"/>x
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="test_2_p2" class="clschk"/>y
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="test_3_p3" class="clschk"/>z
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age"/> <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what `validator.resetForm();` does ?

Comment: i request can u please have a look at this my post and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318962/how-to-perform-conditional-client-side-validation-by-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: @Mou validator.resetForm() remove errors when they are no more needed. The behaviour of this snippet is only to show you a possible way to solve your problem as you asked me. I hope this helped you. Yes I will take a lokk to the other question, but not in this moment. I'm doing other.  Thanks so much

Comment: @Mou I answered to the other question. Could you upvote this question and let me know about the new one? Thanks so much

Comment: i gave u upvote for answer my question in comment section. let me know anything else i could do. thanks